# Best Way to Automate Adding Text to an Image and formatting for Printing?

Tags: printing, automation, photoshop, text-files

**Here's what I have:**

Quarter Sheet Flyer (4 per page) as a PSD or JPG
   Text file with one entry of text per line.

**What I want to do:**

Print out 100 flyers (on 25 pieces of paper)
   Somehow automate the process of adding the text to the image, either via some scripting language or a Photoshop automated task.  Then format the pages to print, either to generate a 25 page PDF file or generate four at a time and send them to the printer page by page.

Anyone have any experience with something like this or have any recommendations on how I should go about doing this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Word automation to generate a word file with the correct text and image, and then just print it.
This would be one of the simpler solutions, you can implement the entire thing as a word macro (VBA).

A more complex solution would be to use VB6 or .net to print the text and the image into the form and then print the form.

You can write a script that will generate an html page with the image and the text, and then print out the html using a browser.